# My formula (using conditional formatting) isn't working across sheets, no error, just no color

Tags: excel

I have a formula that I am using on sheet1 of my document to color a cell based criteria within the sheet. This formula work just fine and I have no issues at all with it.
However, when I tried to use the same formula on a second sheet that is used to long term storage (edited as below) I get no color in that cell at all.

```
=SUMPRODUCT('Item Storage'!$B3:$V3,1/'Weekly Job Progress'!$X18:$X38)/W3>0.95
=SUMPRODUCT('Item Storage'!$B3:$V3,1/'Weekly Job Progress'!$X18:$X38)/W3>=0.9
=SUMPRODUCT('Item Storage'!$B3:$V3,1/'Weekly Job Progress'!$X18:$X38)/W3<0.9
```

'Item storage': Sheet containing the long term storage for items.
'Weekly Job Progress': The main sheet, used for weekly short term storage.

My formula that works in Weekly Job Progress for the same function is very similar, only it references nothing but the cells on the sheet.
I know that I can reference 'Item Storage' for conditional formatting as I have it done for individual cells on the sheet with a similar purpose.

*Edit 1*: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gchi.jpg) is a link to imgur with screenshots of the sheets in question.

Comment: have you confirmed your apply to fields are accurate?

Comment: I did the drag through the cells method to select my cell ranges as well as selecting the final cell for the result to go. I also tried it with the option to just sum the row of hours and not have any total posted for the day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the formula that gets the cells to color correctly. I got it figured out with some additional help outside of here.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(TRANSPOSE('Item Storage'!$B3:$V3),1/'Weekly Job Progress'!$X$18:$X$38)/(SUM($B3:$V3))>0.95
=SUMPRODUCT(TRANSPOSE('Item Storage'!$B3:$V3),1/'Weekly Job Progress'!$X$18:$X$38)/(SUM($B3:$V3))=0.9
=SUMPRODUCT(TRANSPOSE('Item Storage'!$B3:$V3),1/'Weekly Job Progress'!$X$18:$X$38)/(SUM($B3:$V3))<0.9
```

Answer (score 0):

I find it difficult to evaluate without a sample of the cell contents, but it's most likely to do with either the "$" locked cells or `W3`. If `W3` is static (should be the same cell no matter which column or row I apply the formula to), you should lock it with `$W$3`.

Comment: I apologize. [This](https://imgur.com/a/hC2tTfK) is a link to imgur that has the referenced sheets with ranges. The reason I unlocked the row number is that VBA will add a row for the next day which means it needs to keep going forward (I think). This works in cells B:V  as I run it multiple times.